# share label in ggplot facet_wrap to avoid repetition

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

This code

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  facet_wrap(am ~ cyl, ncol = 6) +
  geom_point()
```

produces the following graph

[image]

The variable "am" has two values (0 and 1) that are repeated 3 times each. I wonder whether it is possible to include a single strip with the value 0 centered (and the same for the value 1).

Comment: @RLave I updated the graph to show the type of graph that I am working

Comment: possible duplicate: see answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776079/multiple-titles-in-facet-wrap-ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776079/multiple-titles-in-facet-wrap-ggplot2)